# Razor button onclick call only when condition is true

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to call onclick event on button only when certain condition is met ?

F.e.: I would like to call my onclick event if function call returns number > 0, something like:
if(checkNoOfRows() > 0) //call onclickevent

Is it possible to do this inline ?

Here's my button onclick event, which I would like to call only when certain condition is fulfilled:

```
<button id="btnExportXLSPropsChild" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("exportUserProp", "UserManagement", new { typeToExport = "CHILD" })'">Export</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to do the check on the server or the client?

Comment: I want to do the check on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this check in `razor`, but the syntax is a bit messy.  You need the `<text>` elements so that it doesn't try to parse your `onclick` as code on the server:

```
<div @if (true) { <text>onclick="test"</text>  }></div>
```

However, a better approach would probably be to add the url as an attribute and then bind an event in javascript with the check.  Your template will then be something like:

```
<button id="btnExportXLSPropsChild" data-url="@Url.Action("exportUserProp", "UserManagement", new { typeToExport = "CHILD" })">Export</button>
```

And then in the javascript with jQuery:

```
$("#btnExportXLSPropsChild").on('click', function(){
    if(checkNumberOfRows() > 0){
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to add some parameters to url ? My parameter would come from hidden field, so I can do something like: validFrom = $('hiddenValidFrom').val()

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the inline event and use an event handler instead. From the JavaScript event handler, you can check how many rows exist and conditionally run your function.

```
$("#btnExportXLSPropsChild").on('click', function(){
    if(checkNumberOfRows() > 0){
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but how to call @Url.Action ?

Comment: Just saw this, sorry.

I'd recommend putting the url action as a data attribute on the element and grabbing it from the element with jQuery, or writing the url directly to a javascript variable and setting the location to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery can do the magic for you :

`$('button').click(function(){
     if(condition > 0)
     {
         windown.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")';
     }
});`